# taking elements from all arrayLists one at a time

Tags: java, loops, arraylist

considering there is a structure as described in http://prohost.lt/stack/q.png

In the main arrayList we have n elements(sub arrayLists) (as for image we can consider n=3).

How to make a dynamic loop thru all sub arrayLists so as to get:

sarraylist1.get(0), sarrayList2.get(0), .. sarraylistN.get(0)

In case n=3 it would be

```
for(sarraylist1){
    for( sarraylist2){
        for(sarraylist3){
            element from every list
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Easiest way is with *recursion*, or you can transform the recursion into a loop on the root `arraylist` (similar way as backtrack works)

Comment: Do you have an `ArrayList` as element in `subArrayList` of each `subArrayList` ?

Comment: In my case those sub arrayLists are a little bit more complex structures, so with recursion i would fail. 

I have arrayList of objects. Objects have some attributes + arrayLists (there arrayLists contains other type objects (attribute+arraylists))

Comment: I wouldn't say that with *recursion* is the only way, because every recursive program can be made iterative. But sometimes it is much more difficult.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I misunderstood what you were asking, but would something as simple as this not work?

```
List<List> lists = new ArrayList<List>();
for(List l : lists){
    for(List subl: l)
        Object o = subl.get(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After watching your comment I suggest you to use `recursive approach` to solve your problem.

```
public void recursiveCall(ArrayList list)
{
  for ( Object obj : list)
  {
    if (obj instanceOf ArrayList)
    {
      recursiveCall((ArrayList)obj);
    }
    else
    {
       System.out.print(obj);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your scheme of the image, you can also do it with the "for while loop":

```
for (int mainArrayElements = 0; mainArrayElements < listOfLists.size(); mainArrayElements++) {
    List arraysInMain = ((List)listOfLists.get(mainArrayElements));
    for (int subArrayElements = 0; subArrayElements < arraysInMain.size(); subArrayElements++) {
        List deepArray = ((List)listOfLists.get(subArrayElements));
        for (int innerArrayElements = 0; innerArrayElements <  deepArray.size() ; innerArrayElements++) {
            System.out.println(deepArray.get(innerArrayElements));
        }
    }
}
```

But as mentioned before, recursion would be a really great combo to knock out the problem :).

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you have one `List` containing n `List`s for which you want to get the first, second and so on, element of each list. This code does that.

```
for (int i = 0; i < highestSizeOfChildrenList; i++) {
 List<Object> lstOfItemInChild = new Arraylist<Object>();
  for (List childList : mainList) {
     if (i < childList.size()) {
       lstOfItemInChild.add(childList.get(i));
     }
  }

  // lstOfItemInChild now contains all the element i of the sub arrays
}
```

You will need to know the size of the biggest subList to get all the elements of that list, that is what `highestSizeOfChildrenList` represents.